# Android code to find when antenna is hot due to my or any other app

Tags: android, android-networking

I am new to android. I want to detect programmatically when mobile antenna is hot, meaning, I want to find when there is lot of n/w activity going on due to my or any other app, in general, in a programatic way as part of my business logic. Can some one share code snippet to figure this out. Thanks!

Comment: The ehat you feel in a device when its working isn't generally the antenna, its from the CPU.  That's why CPUs have fans and heat sinks, but antennas don't.  So even if there was a temperature sensor inside the device (some do, some don't), it wouldn't detect network activity.  It would detect CPU activity.

Comment: Sorry I feel I am not clear, by "hot" I do not mean literally temperature wise, I want to say usage wise. I explain saying "I want to find when there is lot of n/w activity going on due to my or any other app" in my question. I just want to know is n/w usage is high or low at a moment.

Answer (score 0):

There is no tempature sensor on antenna, unless it is a custom device. Even if there is this information probably will not going to be available at application layer, because of security, even if it's available antenna would not get that hot from transferring data, even if it heats up, you wouldn't be able to detect it because big enviromental changes, it is not the same in equator and in Nordic countries.

To sum up, it is impossible to do that